# Squeak 5.0 on 64-bit Linux ignores -headless and -nodisplay

Tags: linux, squeak

I am trying to run the new Squeak 5.0 on 64-bit Linux with no display driver.
On an older server I always used -nodisplay or -headless and they worked, however now they are ignored and I get this error message:

```
squeak: could not find any display driver
```

Further details:

- squeak was installed via apt-get
- command line: sudo squeak Squeak5.0-15113.image -headless -nodisplay
- The Linux is a Ubuntu, newly installed by 1&1.

Comment: Can you give more information on the Squeak version installed? For example, which apt repository and which vm version

Comment: Just to cover all bases, can you run an older version of Squeak on the same system? What's the content of your `DISPLAY` environment variable?

Comment: @Tobias The problem why the `-headless -nodisplay` being ignored was I think because the squeak being found is a shell script which for some reason does not forward these arguments to the real executable.

Comment: For that reason i was also at first not able to find out that the executable is indeed very outdated. But getting to run the new squeak5 VM on 64bit turned out far from trivial. I can give details of what I tried, but it would be more helpful for future visitors if someone knows how to do that. (I did not find info on the web)

Comment: @MaxLeske if you still want to know this: no old Squeak Images (4.3) dont work either and `DISPLAY` is empty.

Comment: I will keep trying to get the new Squeak 5 VM to run on 64bit

Comment: We run the old 4.0.3 VM successfully like this: `"/usr/lib/squeak/4.0.3-2202/squeakvm" -mmap 512m -vm-sound-null -vm-display-null Squeak.image" "argName1" "arg1"`

Answer (score 1):

For those who have this problem in the future:

The parameters were ignored because they were not passed from the squeak shellscript to the squeak executable.

You can find the executable in: `Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/Linux-i686/lib/squeak/5.0-3397`

Sidenote: Another trap is if `./squeak` throws the error `file not found` then the permissions are not set (maybe you extracted the file on windows like me and uploaded it to a linux server, the permissions were lost on windows) - then you can `sudo chmod +x squeak`.